# Does the ISS yaw in orbit? And if so, why?

Tags: iss, attitude

A NASA ISS reference guide ([PDF](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/np-2015-05-022-jsc-iss-guide-2015-update-111015-508c.pdf); 37 MB) explains the use of reaction wheels -- Control Moment Gyroscopes (CMGs) -- to control the station's attitude/orientation.

My understanding is the station is actively controlled to keep the nadir always pointing toward the Earth (belly down). This is confirmed by the post: [Why does the ISS rotate exactly once per orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12335/32596)

> [The ISS maintains] a constant attitude relative to Local Vertical Local Horizontal (LVLH).

**Issue:** Most animations show the ISS moving forward section forward, but during the course of one Shuttle flight, that does **not** seem to be the case, which may mean the station is yawed with respect to its zenith-nadir axis (either purposefully or due to some orbital mechanics).

For example, from the STS-115 presentation video [at 4:36](https://youtu.be/9hVj-_zCvTA?&t=273), the view shows the nose-up docked Shuttle moving bay forward, which means the station is moving aft section forward (Russian segment first). That's because the Shuttle was docked on PMA-2 (Destiny forward), meaning if the station is moving Destiny first, it would have been the Shuttle underside moving forward, not the bay door.

During the final fly-around days later [at 12:43](https://youtu.be/9hVj-_zCvTA?&t=763), the station is seen moving Destiny forward.

**Q:** Does (and why if yes) the ISS yaw in orbit? If not, how can that linked view (and others) be explained?

[image]
As seen after STS-115 to avoid configuration confusion (source: linked PDF; modified).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr During ISS assembly the station maneuvered more than it does these days.

You are correct that the docked Shuttle / ISS stack maneuvered during the STS-115 mission.

The planned attitudes for the last several Shuttle missions are available in the Attitude Timeline sections of their flightplans, published at the JSC FDF page. The STS-115 flight plan is [here](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Shuttle/Flight%20Plan/STS-115%20Flight%20Plan%20Basic%20Rev%20A.pdf).

Referencing that (pp 4-5 and 4-6), we can see that for the majority of the docked phase the stack flew in a **Bias -XLV -ZVV** attitude, but maneuvered to a couple of **XPOP** attitudes for deployment of the solar arrays installed by the mission.

> ISS will maneuver to the 4A Solar Array Deploy attitude.  During the
> first insulation [*sic*] period after post sleep, the crew is expected to
> deploy the 4A Solar Array mast to 15.5 bays (49%) then to 31.5 bays
> (100%).  After 4A is deployed and visual verifications are complete,
> the SSRMS will be set up in preparation for 2A Solar Array Deploy.
> ISS will maneuver to the 2A Solar Array Deploy attitude and hand over
> attitude control to shuttle.  Shuttle will maintain attitude control
> during the 2A deploy and for an additional insulation [*sic*] period.  The 2A
> Solar Array mast is deployed to 15.5 bays (49%), held for 30 minutes
> for thermal conditioning and then complete deployment to 31.5 bays
> (100%).  The timeline protects for 1 insulation [*sic*] period per Solar Array
> and an additional insulation [*sic*] period for a contingency deploy.  After
> these three
> insolation periods, due to ISS thermal a 6 hr. recovery period in the
> nominal attitude is required prior to another attempt at deploying.
> Shuttle will maneuver back to the nominal TEA attitude prior to
> handing attitude control back over to ISS.

- -XLV -ZVV means the ISS negative X axis is pointed to the local vertical and the negative Z axis is pointed into the velocity vector.  This "biased -XLV -ZVV" attitude was a torque equilibrium attitude for the stack at this stage of ISS construction when the station was asymmetrical. Torque equilibrium attitudes are explained [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8708/6944).
- XPOP means that the ISS X axis is perpendicular to the orbital plane.

> The X-Axis Perpendicular to Orbit Plane (XPOP) reference frame is
> shown in Figure C-3. XPOP is a quasi-inertial reference frame that can
> be visualized by a 90° yaw of the LVLH frame at orbital noon. The
> X-axis points out of plane, while both the Y- and Z-axes lie in the
> orbital plane. Note that unlike LVLH, which is rotating with the
> Station as the Station rotates about the Earth, XPOP remains fixed
> with the Station X-axis pointing out of plane and the Z-axis is
> aligned with the orbit noon vector. XPOP is a “quasi-inertial”
> reference frame, because as the orbital plane slowly regresses, the
> XPOP reference frame also regresses to keep the X-axis pointing out of
> the orbital plane.

[image]

(XPOP description and image from [here](http://civiliancomms.tripod.com/spacecomms/iss/iss_appendix_c.html))

During the early, asymmetrical stages of ISS construction, various attitudes were used. Some other ones are discussed [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19732/6944).  I can't find the attitude that the proto-ISS was flying in before STS-115 docking, but it was yet another attitude - the flight plan states "The shuttle will maneuver the stack into the Bias -XLV +ZVV attitude" after docking.

Comment: Furthermore (though I have no public documentation to point to that I've found), they have recently been introducing a yaw bias to the attitudes during high beta periods to improve power production.