# Zarya means "dawn". Has it ever faced the rising sun?

Tags: iss, zarya

The first part of the International Space Station launched into orbit was the Russian [*Zarya*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya) module.  When it was connected to the U.S. [*Unity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(ISS_module)) module a few days later, the ISS was born.

*Zarya* is the Russian word for "dawn" or "sunrise".  The name was chosen to signify the dawn of a new age of international space cooperation.

When the ISS passes from the dark side of the Earth to face the "rising" sun, which end faces the sunrise?  **Has *Zarya* ever been the end that faces the sunrise *first*, thus fulfilling its name?**

- Exclude the orbits before it became part of the station.
- Consider only the actual station; ignore visiting vehicles (e.g. Soyuz, Shuttle, Progress).
- The current configuration of the station no longer applies to the question, as *Zarya* is now in the middle of the station, with *Zvezda* at the end.

Comment: Actually, "zarya" can mean both "dawn" and "dusk". The word means a bright band on the horizon before a sunrise or after a sunset, or the time when such a band is present. Though it is also used metaphorically like English "dawn", in expressions like "dawn of a new age".

Comment: there's some interesting stuff [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37792/12102) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19726/12102)

Comment: This word is often used as "the beginning of a new era", "the beginning of a new page in history." For example Krasnaya Zarya - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dawn_(disambiguation)

Comment: So, just to ensure I am bounding the question properly, the time span in play is only that era starting in December 1998 when the shuttle released the proto-ISS consisting of the FGB+Node 1 and ending when the Service Module docked to the FGB in July 2000 ?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response!