# Does Russian mission control still use the callsign "Zarya", and how did that not conflict with the ISS module?

Tags: iss, radio-communication, russia, mission-control, zarya

The Wikipedia page for the [*Salyut* space station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salyut#History_of_Salyut_space_stations) claims

> Initially, the space stations were to be named *Zarya*, the Russian word for 'Dawn'. However, as the launch of the first station in the programme was prepared, it was realised that **this would conflict with the call sign *Zarya* of the flight control centre (TsUP) in Korolyov** – therefore the name of the space stations was changed to *Salyut* shortly before launch of *Salyut* 1

The [initial module of the International Space Station is also called *Zarya*](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43811/26446).  **What was done at the start of the ISS to prevent confusion among the two uses of *Zarya*?**  Was Russian mission control still using that call sign in 1988?  What call sign do they use now?  (Perhaps "Moscow", just as the U.S. uses "Houston"?)

Comment: No reference, but no one in the ops world calls the module Zarya. It's the FGB. Zarya is a PR name like Canadarm, Destiny Node, etc, etc.

Comment: I don't know if this means anything relative to this question or not but in the TLE world the ISS is Zarya https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKKN9.png

Comment: @uhoh it was the first element launched, so in the TLE world all the other bits just got stuck to it.