# How is it possible that the windows on the ISS mostly face Earth only?

Tags: iss, orbital-elements

In [this article](https://futurism.com/milky-way-look-like-iss-2) astronaut Clayton C. Anderson states that on the ISS the windows "mosty face Earth, which means that it is only possible to see the stars at the very edges of the windows, and sometimes not even then."

How is that possible as the ISS is in an orbit, so that all its sides should face all directions throughout an orbital revolution? Is the ISS set to a momentum of rotation on its axis that makes it approximately retain the same orientation relative to the Earth's surface throughout a revolution? If so, why? Is it only to make astronauts be able to look at the Earth through the cupola without having to wait for the correct time during the orbit? And wouldn't that make a slight aritificial gravity due to the slow rotation on its axis?

Post-close edit: Users insisted that it is a duplicate of the linked question above. However, I believe it is a duplicate of the following question, and the answer there answers my question better:

[Why does the ISS rotate exactly once per orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/why-does-the-iss-rotate-exactly-once-per-orbit)

Comment: This is probably answered in one or both of the following: [Why does the ISS rotate exactly once per orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12335/12102) (tl;dr it's a Torque Equilibrium Attitude) and/or [Why does the ISS points always the same side towards the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8701/12102) Different but slightly related: [Does the ISS have zenith-facing windows?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9661/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Thanks, the above posts answer how the ISS makes it, but they don't answer _why_ very well, and I don't understand the reasons much since the ISS is in the (near-)vacuum of space.

Comment: @uhoh Propose rather the first question as duplicate (Why does the ISS rotate exactly once per orbit), not the 2nd one.

Comment: This article explains it quite well: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993asee.nasa.....T/abstract

Comment: @GdD Please propose the first question (Why does the ISS rotate exactly once per orbit) as duplicate, not the 2nd one. I'd accept Why does the ISS rotate exactly once per orbit? as duplicate, respectively this question as duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @Giovanni, it's not your call what people think represents a duplicate, it's a duplicate whether you accept it or not.

Comment: A question can be marked as a duplicate of more than one question. If you feel that the nominated duplicate targets don't adequately answer your question, you can edit your question to explain what particular details those other questions don't address. Ideally, when asking a question you should mention the similar questions that you've looked at, and what further info you need.

Comment: @GdD At first, it was no duplicate if I didn't accept. And I didn't accept the 2nd question. It doesn't matter now because most found it is a duplicate of the 2nd one. I feel the first one answers it better.

Comment: IDK, but if there's a window anywhere that faces _away_ from Earth, then for part of each orbit, it's going to more-or-less face the Sun. I can _imagine_ why they might not want too many of those (or at least, why they might want to put an external shade on it). Also, (just guessing), A window facing Earth from LEO might have less exposure to micrometeoroids, and a window facing away might be more exposed.

Comment: GdD's upvoter, the OP is being asked whether it answers their question. If they refuse, it is not a duplicate.